# How to increase the number of div on the basis of a selectbox input in PHP

Tags: javascript, html, yii2

I want to show/increase the number of div based on the choice of the select box. This is my code of Div which I want to repeat

```
<div class="hh">
    <p>Adults</p>
    <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_adults" id="no_of_adults">
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
    </select>
    <p>Children</p>
    <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_children" id="no_of_children">
        <option value="0">00</option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the code of the select box

```
<p>No of Rooms</p>                                          
<select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_rooms" id="no_of_rooms">
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>                                               
</select>
```

If I select 3 from the select box I need to show 3 `<div class="hh">`

Comment: what 3 is it option or number of adults + childerns?

Comment: I'd use javascript if I were you. Just use the onClick() method to change the html

Comment: if i select 3 from no_of_rooms....i want to show the above div thrice

Comment: @lowa15...is it possible with on change...please give your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
 function hChange(field) {
   console.log(field.value);
        for(i=1;i<6;i++) {
            if(document.getElementById('div'+i)) {
                if(i <= parseInt(field.value))
                    continue;
                else {
                    document.getElementById('div'+i).remove();
                }
            } else if(i <= parseInt(field.value)) {
                $('.hh').append('<div id="div'+i+'"><span>Adults</span> \
                    <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_adults" id="no_of_adults_'+i+'"> \
                    <option value="1">01</option> \
                    <option value="2">02</option> \
                    </select> \
                        <span>Children</span> \
                     <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_children" id="no_of_children'+i+'"> \
                    <option value="0">00</option> \
                    <option value="1">01</option> \
                    <option value="2">02</option> \
                    </select><br></div> ');
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>No of Rooms</p>                                          
<select onchange="hChange(this)" class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_rooms" id="no_of_rooms">
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>                                               
</select>
<div class="hh">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....but No changes.....can you add the other changes which i want to do

Comment: call hChange in onchange of rooms select box

Comment: You should not write HTML in Javascript

Comment: @Burntime what is your problem?

Comment: Its a best practice "Avoid mixing with other technologies" http://codingstyleguide.com/style/219/javascript-avoid-mixing-with-other-technologies

Comment: then change accordingly with createElement function given idea how he can achieve it

Comment: what is your problem boss it is the correct  sol. if you want you follow standards

Comment: we are here to help not for developing all the things.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
  var occupancySelects = $(".hh"),
    template = occupancySelects.find('[data-template="persons_per_room"]');

  $("#no_of_rooms").on("change", function(event) {
    var numOfRooms = event.currentTarget.value;

    clean();

    if (numOfRooms > 1) {
      clone(numOfRooms);
    }

  });

  function clean() {
    occupancySelects.find('[data-clone="persons_per_room"]').remove();
  }

  function clone(numOfRooms) {
    for (var i = 1; i < numOfRooms; i++) {
      var templateClone = template.clone();

      templateClone
        .attr("data-template", "")
        .attr("data-clone", "persons_per_room");

      occupancySelects.append(templateClone);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>No of Rooms</p>
<select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_rooms" id="no_of_rooms">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <option value="3">03</option>
  <option value="4">04</option>
  <option value="5">05</option>
</select>

<div class="hh">
  <div data-template="persons_per_room">
    <p>Adults</p>
    <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_adults">
      <option value="1">01</option>
      <option value="2">02</option>
    </select>
    <p>Children</p>
    <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="no_of_children">
      <option value="0">00</option>
      <option value="1">01</option>
      <option value="2">02</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```